# Уточняющий оборот(2)

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

"Сегодня был день рождения Никиты, одиннадцатое мая, и назначено поднятие флага на пруду".

Уточняющий оборот чем выражен? Я просто не знаю, как его подчеркнуть. По вопросу - какой или что? А так это время

Answer (score 1):

*Сегодня был день рождения Никиты*,(какой именно день?) *одиннадцатое мая, и назначено поднятие флага на пруду*.

Это уточняющее приложение - особый вид определения, выраженный именем существительным, у нас числительное + существительное, подчёркиваем как определение.